# reading file and then writing against a variable in the same file

Tags: shell

I have a file where few parameter is specified like load_start_date, load_end_date etc. like below. I also have a variable in that same file called part_date.

```
load_start_date=2016-10-03
load_end_date=2016-10-03

part_date=
```

Now my intention is to read the file (specifically read the load_start_date parameter) , deduct 1 day (i.e. for this example it will be 2016-10-02) and then convert the format as YYYYMMDD (e.g. 20161003) save save the value against the variable part_date like below.

```
load_start_date=2016-10-03
load_end_date=2016-10-03

part_date=20161002
```

how easily this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest taking advantage from the fact that the strings in your file are well suited for assignment:

```
#!/bin/bash -
{
  source file.txt
  if test "$load_start_date" != ""; then
    part_date=$(date -d "$load_start_date - 1 day" "+%Y%m%d")

    sed -i -e "s/^part_date=.*/part_date=$part_date/" file.txt
  fi
}
```

The `source` command evaluates `file.txt` in the current context, i.e. creates variables `$load_start_date`, `$load_end_date`, and `$part_date`. This would have been a little bit unsafe, if we hadn't used *subshell* expression (the curly braces) which creates special scope for the block of code.

Then we simply assign the date before `$load_start_date` to `$part_date` variable, then replace corresponding line in the source file by means of `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `date` command in your script:

```
part_date=$(date -d @$(($(date -d $load_start_date +%s) - 24*60*60)) +%Y%m%d)
```

This will convert the start date in seconds and substract 1 day from that value, then print again in the YYYYMMDD format.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, and you have a file say `file.txt` containing:

```
load_start_date=2016-10-03
load_end_date=2016-10-03
```

and your goal is to read (or source) that file and set the variable `part_date` to one day less that that shown in `load_start_date` (with the `-` removed), then in addition to the `date` approach, you can simply use POSIX parameter substitution and arithmetic. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -f "dat/lsd.txt" ] && . file.txt          ## source file in script

test -n "$load_start_date" || exit 1        ## validate load_start_date

# part_date=$((${load_start_date//-/} - 1))   ## if your shell supports
                                              ## parameter substitution

part_date="${load_start_date%%-*}"          ## otherwise, us POSIX
tmp="${load_start_date#*-}"                 ## parameter expansion
part_date="${part_date}${tmp%-*}"
part_date="${part_date}${load_start_date##*-}"

part_date=$((part_date - 1))                ## subtract 1

printf "part_date : %s\n" "$part_date"
```

(**note:** if your shell supports parameter substitution, you can reduce the four lines used to isolate the date without the `'-'` to a single line shown commented above)

Once the `'-'` are removed, you have a simple integer (e.g. `20161003`), and simply arithmetic is all that is needed to reduce the value by 1.

**Example Use/Output**

```
part_date : 20161002
```

There are many ways you can approach this. Look over all the answers and see which one fits your needs the best.